# My layout is not working

Tags: css, html

How can I place the 5th and so on images next to the first 4 images? what kind of css style rules do I need for this? at the moment I have a div which floats left :

```
div#leftcontainer {
    float: left;
    height: 30%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

This contains 2 divs with each 4 images in it. The second one has a float right:

```
.topshops-section-secondcol {
    float: right;
    position: static;
}
```

At the moment the 2 sets of 4 images are just displayed on top and not next to one another?
jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Gn7PL/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this: [**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Gn7PL/1/)

You had to close `<div id="leftcontainer"></div>`

In its current state, left container contained the right container, thus the CSS wasn't effecting it. Other than that, everything else was perfectly fine. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ueWea/) .Don't use too much css and elements.just go with simple

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <img src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-2hC1XUCLbZQ/TpUrgzmXbqI/AAAAAAAAfts/bR367hj_o2w/s90-c-k-no/2011-10-12_11-50-37_HDR.jpg" />
    </li>
     <li>
        <img src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-2hC1XUCLbZQ/TpUrgzmXbqI/AAAAAAAAfts/bR367hj_o2w/s90-c-k-no/2011-10-12_11-50-37_HDR.jpg" />
    </li>


....etc
```

**CSS**

```
li{
    margin:20px;
    list-style-type:none;

}
```